# Data Set, Concatenation, Creating Coordinates, and Errors

Tags: python, concatenation, latitude-longitude, geopandas

I am trying to find a way where I can take the latitude and longitude, and put them into one set so that it looks like a coordinate and later on I can plug it in for more analysis. 
I'm trying concatenating but it doesn't yield a pair of coordinates. Another problem is that in one case, I had the latitude and longitude flipped when I need them in this order respectively.

```
import geopandas as gpd

fp = "/Users/nsnsksksks/Documents/nsnsnsns/NGGE6AFL.shp"

data = gpd.read_file(fp)

enugu = data.loc[data['ADM1FIPSNA'] == 'Enugu']


for var in enugu: 
    long = str(enugu.LONGNUM)
    lat = str(enugu.LATNUM)
    loc = lat + ', ' + long

    print(loc)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you want as your output (you mentioned set, but I wouldn't keep coords in set, because lat and long could get mixed up and you probably want to make sure you know what number is what. If you want to learn more about sets you can read https://realpython.com/python-sets), so I made two example versions.

If you want just separate strings like "20.23425,14.14145" then:

```
for long, lat in zip(enugu.geometry.x, enugu.geometry.y):
    coords = str(long) + ", " + str(lat)
    #You can do something with your coords then..
```

If you want list of tuples, then:

```
coords = []
for long, lat in zip(enugu.geometry.x, enugu.geometry.y):
    coords.append((long, lat))
```

Result of this one will be like:
[ (12.2134, 12.1452), (34.2524, 21.1201), ... ]

You can easly adapt this code to any data structure you might need, like 2d numpy arrays etc